# Failure using jquery.validate.min in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, jquery-validate

I use jquery.validate.min.js version 1.9 and jquery-1.7.1.js. and i have error on validation form: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'form': object is null or undefined on line 102 :

```
valid: function() {
        if ( $(this[0]).is('form')) {
            return this.validate().form();
        } else {
            var valid = true;
            var validator = $(this[0].form).validate();
            this.each(function() {
                valid &= validator.element(this);
            });
            return valid;
        }
    },
```

I was try to use jquery-1.5.2.js and standart  jquery.validate.min.js but this is not work.
My code in site.js is :

```
$(".boxy-wrapper #genericleadform").validate({
        errorElement: "",
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).addClass("notvalid");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).removeClass("notvalid");
        }
    });
```

Generic lead form html is:

```
     <form action="/BeautyLotery/Leads/Add" class="tot_form" id="genericleadform" method="post" name="genericleadform"> 
    <div class="lead_wrapper"> 
<fieldset> 
    <input class="required toto_imp1" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" /> <input class="required toto_imp2" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" /> <input class="required phonenumber toto_imp3" id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="" /> 
    <input class="required emailenglish toto_imp4" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" /> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" class="agreement_link"></a> 
    <label class="custom_checkbox cc1"><input type="checkbox" /><b></b></label> 
    <label class="custom_checkbox cc2"><input type="checkbox" /><b></b></label> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="submit_button"></a> 
    <div class="pp_msg hidden"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pp_msg_close"></a> </div> 
    </fieldset> </div> 
    </form>
```

I don't understand what is problem... Can anybody help?

Comment: Perhaps post the form html too?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for having `href="javascript:void(0)"`, or any inline JavaScript, when you're using jQuery.  With a proper click event handler, you could just use `href="#"`, as one example.  Or you could assign a click event handler to literally any other type of element and avoid the `href` altogether.

Comment: href="#" is jumping page up and javascript:void(0) is not... why is relevant for my problem?

Comment: It will not jump the page if you correctly return false in the onclick or use e.preventDefaul() in the jQuery. Anyway - please post the FORM HTML and not the template. We still have no clue as to how your html looks

Comment: "href="#" is jumping page up" - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: You did not fully understand my comment.  _"**With a proper click event handler**, you could just use `href="#"`"_.  'Properly' implementing this includes `preventDefault()` which blocks the default behavior of a `href="#"`.  This is the best way, not `javascript:void(0)` or any other inline JavaScript, especially when you're already using jQuery.  It's not relevant for your problem, which is why I posted it as a _comment_ and not an answer.

Comment: Did you surround your `$(".boxy-wrapper #genericleadform").validate({})` block with a `document.ready`?